# I'm having trouble understanding a "fronted concessive clause"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, parsing, concessives

> Well-intentioned though many people may have imagined that the CIA probably thought they were, their foreign-policy operations were
>   confused, duplicitous failures.

I do understand the basic structure, "Well-intentioned though they were"

But, I can't parse clearly "Well-intentioned though **many people may have imagined that the CIA probably thought** they were".

It just doesn't seem to be a relative clause though.
Could you help me to understand the **parenthesis**?

My parsing is as follows:

The CIA probably thought (that) many people may have imagined [that they were well-intentioned]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people

May have imagined

That the CIA probably thought

They were well-intentioned.

(People are imagining (the CIA thinking (the CIA were well-intentioned)))